# Question tags for the modal need

Tags: tag-questions, semi-modals

What question tag should be used with the modal NEED?

> Nobody need hurry, need they?

or

> Nobody need hurry, do they?

or both are wrong?

Comment: [correction: Nobody need**s** to hurry].

Comment: I am asking about the modal need.

Comment: You need to correct your grammar first. Anyway, the verb "need" is not a modal.

Comment: I don't need to correct my grammar first. If I do it, I won't be asking questions here. If you think need is not a modal then you are welcome to read this https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/need

Comment: "Nobody need hurry" is negative, so the choice is between the positive tags "do they?" and "need they?" The rule is that if the anchor verb is an auxiliary, select the same verb, otherwise select "do". Since "need" is an auxiliary here, it follows that the tag should be "need they?"

Comment: Some of the comments here and on my answer below don't make sense with the question now changed! Neither of the options presented were options in the original question!  The rule for editing is to *clarify meaning without changing it* and it seems to me this is a similar, but different, question to the original.

Comment: I repeat: x needs to hurry. is **not semi-modal**.  But: "Nobody need hurry". is semi-modal, without to. For: need to hurry, the answer from Lifelong Learner is accurate.

Comment: @LifelongLearner Your answer still makes sense. Lambie, "Nobody need to hurry" could have been an error either for "Nobody needs to hurry" (as you assumed) or for the modal "Nobody need hurry" (as was in fact the case, since that's what the OP intended). In any case, the OP has corrected the question since then, so there's no point in continuing to criticise it.

Comment: @rjpond: The OP did not know the difference as the original question was *calling* **to hurry** a modal and trying to say what I said was wrong. What I said was correct for: need to hurry. The original formulation.

Comment: @Lambie this is what you said "Anyway, the verb "need" is not a modal"

Comment: @user1425 It isn't modal in the way you originally presented which was: need to hurry. Need to hurry, have to hurry, have got to hurry= No **modals**. You kept saying modal and only NOW changed it to: need hurry. Seems to be some bad faith there. I was clear about what was not modal. I even gave those examples.

Comment: @ Lambie seems like all you want to accomplish is show that someone doesn't know something while you know it. If I didn't know the difference I wouldn't have asked the question and corrected it. This is my right to correct. You want to look smart at the expense of a typo? If you knew that NEED can be modal you would have never said "Anyway, the verb "need" is not a modal."

Comment: @ Lambie the matter is that at first you said  "Anyway, the verb "need" is not a modal." which means you didn't mean the need in my sentence but any need.

Comment: Nope, you can't get away with that. I merely stated a fact **based on how you presented it**. I cannot be responsible for your initial mistake, can I? The typo is a separate issue. You can correct all you want but you ignored what I said. You might want to admit it. No, it meant the "need to know" as presented in my example: need to know, have to know, have got to know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121284/discussion-between-user1425-and-lambie).

Answer (score 3):

As a British speaker I would expect:

Nobody **needs** to hurry, **do** they?

However, and in response to your comment, we *could* also say

Nobody **need** hurry, **need** they?

The second option sounds strange but is also correct (in my opinion).

My understanding is that if you use 'need' and 'to' you are using need as a main verb, not as a semi-modal verb.  (Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/need)

Comment: But it's not the modal need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  We say he / she / it / they / nobody / everybody needs and I / you / we need

Comment: No. Need is a semi-modal verb.

Comment: Absolutely, need is not a modal. And we do use "do they". And yes, "need they" is also right though less heard perhaps.

Comment: Need can be embodied in two entities: 1 as a main verb, 2 as a modal verb. That's why it's called a semi-modal verb.

Comment: Nobody has to hurry. Nobody has got to hurry. Nobody needs hurry. None of those is modal and they all mean the same thing.

Comment: None of them is modal because you made them that way. But in my question NEED is modal. Who is asking the question?

Comment: "Nobody need hurry" isn't modal?

Comment: @Lambie It's not modal in your examples, but it's modal in "Nobody need hurry", "You needn't have bothered" or "Need I go on?".

Comment: @lifelong have a look https://www.quora.com/Grammar-Which-question-tags-are-used-with-need-and-neednt

Comment: The example given by the OP is **not modal**, and means the **same thing as**: have/have got to....

Comment: @ Lambie How did you come to the conclusion that it's not modal? What is the evidence you can submit to prove your statement?

Comment: @user1425 on your quora page it uses "He needn't ..., need he" - we wouldn't say "nobody needn't", we would say "nobody need" or, more likely, the non-modal "nobody needs to". The quora link also makes the point that this construct sounds odd. Also see the link I posted about using 'need' and 'to' which explains that need isn't modal when used that way.

Comment: @LifelongLearner "Nobody need hurry" doesn't sound odd to me (nor does "Nobody need hurry, need they?"). That said, on the Collins dictionary page cited earlier by the OP, we see these examples: 'She need know', 'She needn't know'. The first of those ("She need know") sounds so odd to me as to be virtually unacceptable. The second ("she needn't know") is fine. I think it's primarily in negative sentences and interrogatives that we use modal "need". Affirmative sentences like "she needs to know" are almost always non-modal. ("Only" has a degree of negative force, so "she need only know" is OK.)

Comment: "Nobody need hurry" is negative, so the choice is between the positive tags "do they?" and "need they?" The rule is that if the anchor verb is an auxiliary, select the same verb, otherwise select "do". Since "need" is an auxiliary here, the tag should be "need they?"

Comment: @BillJ that's what I also thought (e.g. need they), but I came across a lot of criticism of this tag. Which left me puzzled.

Comment: The question says: **Nobody need[s] *to* hurry**. It does not say: **Nobody need hurry**. Of course, "need hurry" is that semi-modal. But, "need to hurry" is the same as: has to hurry or have got to hurry, and is **not semi-modal**. It is the **main verb**.

Comment: @Lambie - the question has been changed! As per my comment on the question it's not the same question now, arguably similar, but it's not the same!

Comment: @LifelongLearner Your answer is correct for: need to hurry AND for need hurry.  The OP never asked about: need hurry. People seem to not have realized this. And you are **right**: need hurry is modal. And need to hurry is not. :) The OP has "need to hurry" and is calling **that** a modal.